# How to reference one Node value in Other Node in firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Suppose there are two **Users A and B**.

This is the node structure for **User A** who has Friends. Now as in above image, there is UserId, Name, City etc.. Name and City is being added from **User B's** UserProfile data..

But the problem is if **User B** updates his Name or City, then that change is not being reflected in **User A's** Friends node.
So, how to associate/reference **User B's** Name, City to **User A's** Friends Node..

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hey Frank, thanks for your reply..I visited above link given by you.. and got the solution for that..

Comment: Good to hear Raghav!